# How to set function as value to property that expects anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery API - `jquery DataTables` and I have this code snippet :

```
oSettings.aoDrawCallback.push({
    "fn": function(){

    },
    "sName": "user"
});
```

Inside the body of the function I want to execute an `Ajax` request. when I write it drectly here like so:

```
"fn": function(){
 $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    }),
```

There is more that is just an example to show the way everything's work fine. Then I create my own function :

```
function initCredits(id, inputVal, chkSelected) {

console.log(id);
$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: data
    success: function (data) {
    }
 })
 }
```

and try to assing it do `fn` like so:

```
oSettings.aoDrawCallback.push({
    "fn": initCredits(id, inputVal, chkSelected),
    "sName": "user"
});
```

which gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. Now the text comes from the `jquery DataTables` API but there may be only two reasons I can think of that may break my code, since it's working befor taking it to outer function. First - I'm tryng to assing the function in a wrong way and second - as you may see I need three variables for my ajax request `(id, inputVal, chkSelected)` which are collected from the function where I'm doing this :

```
oSettings.aoDrawCallback.push({
    "fn": initCredits(id, inputVal, chkSelected),
```

but the console log shows that the values are correct so I think this is less likely to be the problem, but still I consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
"fn": initCredits(id, inputVal, chkSelected),
```

… **calls** the function and assigns **the return value**.

To assign the function, just do:

```
"fn": initCredits,
```

Comment: Getting a very strange error. Can't think how it has something to do with this problem, but with `"fn": initCredits,` I get this jquery error : `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.`

Comment: `"fn": function () { initCredits(id, inputVal, chkSelected) },` is working though. Dunno why I didn't try it before posting here. Thanks for the help. Any idea why this works, and I believe your suggestion should work too, but obviously there's something more here?

Comment: It depends on where the arguments are supposed to come from. My approach assumes they come from whatever calls the function, yours assumed they already exist in the current scope.

Comment: Aha, yeah, you are totally right. They are in the scope. Thanks for clarification!